# The method or operation is not implemented in CustomRoleProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, roleprovider

I am implementing custom role provider for my website.In my web.config file i have add the following code.
web.config

```
  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
  <providers>
  <clear/>
  <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="MvcMembership.Models.CustomRoleProvider"  applicationName="MvcMembership"/>
  </providers>
  </roleManager>
```

I have overdie the createRole method and  also initialized the database in initialize method but it is giving error at this line

Comment: can you post the exact error ur getting?

Comment: go to debug > exception and check the CLR exceptions thrown and run the application. it will take you directly to the exception on where it is being thrown from. copy and paste the exact exception and the line of code

Comment: public override string ApplicationName
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        } it is giving error at this line throw new NotImplementedException and the error is method or operation is not implemeted.

Comment: When you write a custom provider you need to write the functionality inside it. By default all the methods contains `NotImplementedException` Are you surprised that when you run `throw new NotImplementedException` it throws an error?